# How to Fix Shopify Rest API Product Upload Error?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, axios, shopify

How can i fix this error or how should I change the format?

Product is coming mongoDB like this.

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("64db3748a42f997c0544eda0"),
  id: 'LORENZO-CAM_COBALTO',
  shopifyId: 'none',
  site: 'Brands Distribution',
  whichStore: 'uk',
  title: 'Duca di Morrone LORENZO CAM COBALTO',
  body_html: '<p>Made in: Italy<br/>Collection: Spring/Summer<br/>Gender: Man<br/>Type: Loafers<br/>Upper: suede<br/>Internal lining: leather<br/>Sole: rubber<br/>Details: round toe</p>',
  vendor: 'Duca di Morrone',
  product_type: 'Shoes',
  variants: [
    {
      option1: 'EU 40',
      option2: 'Blue',
      title: 'Bodies',
      price: 29,
      inventory_management: 'shopify',
      inventory_quantity: 9
    },
    {
      option1: 'EU 41',
      option2: 'Blue',
      title: 'Bodies',
      price: 29,
      inventory_management: 'shopify',
      inventory_quantity: 18
    },
    {
      option1: 'EU 42',
      option2: 'Blue',
      title: 'Bodies',
      price: 29,
      inventory_management: 'shopify',
      inventory_quantity: 37
    },
    {
      option1: 'EU 43',
      option2: 'Blue',
      title: 'Bodies',
      price: 29,
      inventory_management: 'shopify',
      inventory_quantity: 48
    },
    {
      option1: 'EU 44',
      option2: 'Blue',
      title: 'Bodies',
      price: 29,
      inventory_management: 'shopify',
      inventory_quantity: 43
    },
    {
      option1: 'EU 45',
      option2: 'Blue',
      title: 'Bodies',
      price: 29,
      inventory_management: 'shopify',
      inventory_quantity: 33
    },
    {
      option1: 'EU 46',
      option2: 'Blue',
      title: 'Bodies',
      price: 29,
      inventory_management: 'shopify',
      inventory_quantity: 11
    },
    {
      option1: 'EU 40',
      option2: 'Brown',
      title: 'Bodies',
      price: 29,
      inventory_management: 'shopify',
      inventory_quantity: 12
    },
    {
      option1: 'EU 41',
      option2: 'Brown',
      title: 'Bodies',
      price: 29,
      inventory_management: 'shopify',
      inventory_quantity: 18
    },
    {
      option1: 'EU 42',
      option2: 'Brown',
      title: 'Bodies',
      price: 29,
      inventory_management: 'shopify',
      inventory_quantity: 36
    },
    {
      option1: 'EU 43',
      option2: 'Brown',
      title: 'Bodies',
      price: 29,
      inventory_management: 'shopify',
      inventory_quantity: 44
    },
    {
      option1: 'EU 44',
      option2: 'Brown',
      title: 'Bodies',
      price: 29,
      inventory_management: 'shopify',
      inventory_quantity: 43
    },
    {
      option1: 'EU 45',
      option2: 'Brown',
      title: 'Bodies',
      price: 29,
      inventory_management: 'shopify',
      inventory_quantity: 30
    },
    {
      option1: 'EU 46',
      option2: 'Brown',
      title: 'Bodies',
      price: 29,
      inventory_management: 'shopify',
      inventory_quantity: 13
    }
  ],
  images: [
    {
      src: 'https://www.brandsdistribution.com/prod/product-133457-1511628552.jpg/large.jpg'
    },
    {
      src: 'https://www.brandsdistribution.com/prod/product-133457-1658920071.jpg/large.jpg'
    },
    {
      src: 'https://www.brandsdistribution.com/prod/product-133457-1208489454.jpg/large.jpg'
    },
    {
      src: 'https://www.brandsdistribution.com/prod/product-133457-223769419.jpg/large.jpg'
    },
    {
      src: 'https://www.brandsdistribution.com/prod/product-133457-1617393261.jpg/large.jpg'
    }
  ],
  __v: 3
}
```

My post:

```
let response = await modules.axios.post(`https://${datas.config[findProduct.whichStore].shop}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-07/products.json`, {
                product: {
                    ...findProduct._doc,
                    variants: variantsArr
                }
            }, {
                headers: {
                    'X-Shopify-Access-Token': datas.config[findProduct.whichStore].api
                }
            })
            findProduct.shopifyId = response.data.product.id
            findProduct.save()
            functions.log(`${response.data.product.id} is added!`, 0, datas.config[findProduct.whichStore].shop)
            return response.data
```

Error is here:
{ errors: { base: [ "The variant 'EU 40' already exists." ] } }

I'm getting the error I mentioned above when uploading products to my Shopify store. My goal is to be able to add the color, size and stock number of each variety to the store. When I read the API documentation, I couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can provide you some advice, you can go with it or not. First off, you are using really old code style for an API setup in Shopify that is deprecated. Your code will stop working pretty soon. For one thing, inventory management is now a separate section when creating products (inventory item) and it deals with a location. Secondly, and more importantly for you, when dealing with options, first off, you provide their names as in:

```
product: {
  options: ["Size", "Colour", ""]
  ...
```

This lets Shopify know what your options even are. Secondly, when adding new variants then, you provide the values of these options, as in "EU 40" etc, making sure that each pair is unique. So again, with the options, but this time in the variant array:

```
product: {
   variants: [ {
     options: ["EU 40", "Blue", '']
     ...
```

Try that. It works. I have made tens of thousands of products with GQL calls and they always work when I do these simple settings.